# Stopping training at maximum validation accuracy. Is this a good practice?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training my model with a dataset of 200 images. I have created a binary classification CNN that looks like this one:

```
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding a first convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(48, 3, input_shape = (320, 320, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D())

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(48, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D())

# Adding a third convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(48, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D())

#Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())



#Full connected
classifier.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
#Full connected
classifier.add(Dense(256, activation = 'sigmoid'))

#Dropout
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

#Full connected
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))


# Compiling the CNN
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
classifier.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.summary()
```

I am also using Image Data Augmentation and Early Stopping based on val_accuracy with a patience of 10.

My results are the following:

[Result graph validation accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJY7z.png)

The best validation accuracy I get is 0.9231 at the 21st epoch. Should I stop the training with a custom callback once I surpass 92% or is it a bad practice?
Would it be a good practice to set a custom callback that stops training

Comment: If you stop at 92%, how do you know if your model might be able to reach, say, 95% with more training? There is a reason for using a "patience" parameter.

Comment: @xdurch0 Because I have run the model multiple times and the best one I have got is 92%, but after that it drops again

Comment: try reducing/halfing the learning rate when/before the accuracy drops

Comment: @TheodorPeifer how can I do this codewise? I don't have much experience in keras

Comment: Im using pytorch and I just save the model every epoch and hit crtl+c when I want to stop. Then I change the lr by hand and start training again from the last checkpoint. But Im sure there are more elegant solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice here is to save the model every time the validation accuracy hits a maximum, but to keep training. Alternatively, you could save a model after each epoch, and choose the best one to use by checking the validation graph (I'd suggest epoch 11 here. After 11 the validation graph is just oscillating, which is mostly noise).

Finally, 200 images is rarely enough to get good results. You want thousands or tens of thousands at least. Even your validation set should have at least 100 images so that even minor changes to the model show smooth changes in the validation curve. You should also consider adding some data augmentation if you aren't doing it already.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I am going to try these. I know about the small dataset... unfortunately I can't do anything more than data augmentation